# Mail not getting to users on Google when MX records specified in Amazon Route 53

Tags: godaddy, amazon-ec2, mx-record, amazon-route53

I configured the MX on my Amazon AWS Route53 and I was told that some of the users don't get any emails with this domain. 
When I send myself an email everything works fine now, and I doubt that amazon are having minor problems like this, and I can't find any problem.

Can you point out the problem of why this is happening? 
I attached a prntscrn of my Route53 record(ignore the yellow notes):

[image]

More in depth of what I did if needed:

- I have a domain registered on Godaddy.
- I have an EC2 server with a website running on it.
- I defined the domain on Route 53 (created a "Record Set" that is: example.com)
- Created a new Record Set for MX.
- Created a new Record Set IPV4 that uses the Public IP of my EC2 server as a value).
- Pasted the 4 DNSs from the NS Record Set row on my Godaddy account instead the existing -standard ones.

edit:

MX value:

20 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com

10  aspmx.l.google.com

30  aspmx2.googlemail.com

20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com

30 aspmx3.googlemail.com

Comment: Why did you black out the Google Email MX?  The error could be in that.

Comment: 20 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com
10 aspmx.l.google.com
30 aspmx2.googlemail.com
20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com
30 aspmx3.googlemail.com

Comment: Give us the domain name. It's usually something obvious when we have that. That, or the missing emails are just in their spam boxes.

Comment: I have no permission to write the domain name here.